# How to redirect/navigate to a new page while keeping chat bot in same screen?

Tags: reactjs, chatbot

I have been trying to create a react based chatbot, in that if a user presses an option/button from chatbot I want to display a component outside of chatbot and on same page. I have tried adding a popup function, breadcrumbs for side navigation but not able to display it outside of chatbot It is showing everything inside it.I  don't want to refresh my page. How can I do that in ReactJS?

Comment: add some code please

Comment: it's more a CSS question. just you need to render chat dialog box absolute on top of all other components. like Floating Action buttons, or like feedback box, ...

Comment: Can you be more specific ? As i am a beginner I am not able to understand your point . it would be nice of you if you could add some piece of code for better understanding . Thanks in advance . @Amir-Mousavi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you have some sort of client-side routing.

Whatever you want ouside of chatbot:

```
function YourApp() {
  <React.Fragment>
    <Chatbot>  // Chatbot should be outside of route changes
    <Router>    
      <Whatever component your route decides to render>
    <Router>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Also, use CSS to position your chatbot on top of all things.

Comment: This is working fine But my requirement is like , when I click a button in the chatbot , content should be displayed outside the chatbot .

Comment: What kind of routing are you using?

Comment: I have used side bar navigation but right now i am not using any .

Comment: @krupaChaudhari can you share some code with minimal functionality?

Comment: function YourApp() {
  <React.Fragment>
    <Chatbot steps ={steps}>  
    <Router>    
  <App />    < /Router>
  </React.Fragment>
}// In Steps i am calling one component which is having an button after clicking on that button I want to display my data outside of the chatbot .Since I am calling the component from steps I am not able to pass any props from parent to child .

Comment: Can you edit the question and add somre more code? What is `steps`? This other component, can't you call it through a route change? Like, `Steps` has a button that triggers a route change and that other component renders based on the new route?